# Facebook Connect API is not creating session in iPhone

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-ios-sdk

I want to post on Facebook via Facebook connect library in iPhone. I am using  http://www.mobisoftinfotech.com/blog/iphone/iphone-fbconnect-facebook-connect-tutorial/ library. After filling all keys [ API+Secret keys ]. Application runs successfully.

But when I fill Facebook credentials on Facebook login form and tap "Log In". It does not do nothing and it fires `sessionDidNotLogin` function.

I am filling right API+Secret keys. Please guide.

I am using iPhone 4.3 Simulator.

Any other Facebook API, Document, Code Sample would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

https://github.com/reallylongaddress/iPhone-Facebook-Graph-API